# vim insertion with text object (append to end of tag)

Tags: vim

Is there a possiblity to append to a text object in vim, e.g. simlirat to `cit` but not changing but appending? Like `ait`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vit<Esc>a` should do it (select tag, unselect - the cursor remains on the last char in the tag; then append)

Comment: vitA is a bit less painfull, Thank you very much, I haven't thought about visual mode actually

Comment: Weird, I could have sworn I tried it and it didn't work (although I believed it should have). Yeah, `vitA` it is.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in command for that. The closest I can think of would be:

```
vat<Esc>a    " append
vato<Esc>i   " prepend
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't taken visual mode into account, I like to append within the tag. See Amadans answer. Thanks anyway